# Copy Paste on Command Line Ubuntu on Virtual Box with Cygwin Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, virtualbox, cygwin, copy-paste

What is a command line tool that enables copy paste text on ubuntu, also Is it possible to paste on Host machine that is copied from a virtual box, on a Cygwin terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether your VM lets you bring the cursor out of the operating system, kind of like a laptop with an external monitor; you can just middle click in mintty.exe. Then again, there's a chance that I have no clue what I'm talking about since I don't vm. If that doesn't work, I would use some command-line accessible pastebin.

Comment: Can you recommand a command line tool, I can use the mouse to copy-paste, but i want a quick command line equivalent of that. @averagejoey2000